# Set hash value at arbitrary location

Tags: ruby

I am working on an application where I'd like to modify part of an existing hash that looks like:

```
{a: {b: {c: 23}}}
```

to be:

```
{a: {b: {c: [23]}}}
```

However, the exact key to be set is dynamic and at an unknown depth in the hash.  Is there a way to set a value in a hash given an array of keys?  I'm hoping for something like:

```
my_hash['a','b','c'] = new_value
```

Getting a value from an arbitrary depth is straightforward via recursion, but since the traversal works on copies of the data, rather than references, I don't know a way to set the value without rebuilding the entire array during traversal.

Comment: Questions: 1) Does the recursion/traversal *have* to work on a copy of the data for any reason? 2) At the point in code when you are traversing the copy, do you have a reference to the original data structure (e.g. is it stored in a variable that is in scope)?

Comment: 1) It does not have to work on a copy.
2) A reference to the original structure is available
The end goal would be to patch Hash for my application so that I can call my_hash['a','b','c'] or my_hash.set_value_at['a','b','c'].

Comment: You cannot do that. Both input and expected output are invalid.

Comment: `{a: {b: {c: {23}}}}` is not syntactically correct

Comment: Sorry, corrected question syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

except for the syntax (`my_hash['a','b','c']`), the following will do what you want

```
h = {a: {b: {c: { e: 23}}, d: 34}}
keys = ['a','b','c']

def replace_nested_value_by(h, keys, value)
  if keys.size > 1
    replace_nested_value_by(h[keys.first.to_sym], keys[1..-1], value)
  elsif keys.size == 1
    h[keys.first.to_sym] = value
  end
end

puts h
replace_nested_value_by(h, keys, 42)
puts h
```

Comment: Not seen `crawl` before, and not available in `irb` to me - where does it come from?

Comment: When answering, I've changed the function name, and forget to change it when calling it. see my previous edit, it is correct now.

Comment: @toch OP gave `{a: {b: {c: {23}}}}` which is completely different from your hash `{a: {b: {c: 23}}}`. How you do use it?

Comment: That's my fault.  Edited original question to be valid.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu `{a: {b: {c: {23}}}}` not correct, I've stated it was a typo, and @superlou meant `{a: {b: {c: 23}}}`

Comment: This solves my specific use-case, though would it just be changing the elsif clause to be `h[keys.first.to_sym]=value` to implement `replace_leaf_value_by_value(h, keys, value)`?  Would it also function if you need to address a key that isn't a leaf?

Answering my own question, the answer to both is yes, it works.

Comment: @superlou I've updated my answer to set it to a given value. and yes it works even if not a leaf (I've changed the fct name for a better one)

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to toch's answer and just a bit beyond comment scope, I'll also suggest that this can be a good place to use `inject`:

```
def nested_replace(hash, *keys, last_key, value)
  result = keys.inject(hash) { |r, k| r[k] }
  result[last_key] = value
end

h = {a: {b: {c: [23]}}}
nested_replace h, :a, :b, :c, 42
puts h
# => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>42}}}
```

Personally, I tend to prefer Ruby's enumerators if there's a natural way to express things there before looking at recursion.

Comment: I like the enumerations as well, and can pass in the hash location as an array by ```nested_replace(h, *[:a, :b, :c], 42)``` (was non-obvious to me at first, so posting in case someone else comes looking).